# Blender smoke not rendering in 2.75

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, baking

I saw similar reports by other users, with no real solution.

The issue is smoke is displayed properly in the 3d view but not rendered.
Material and texture settings are exactly the same as with Quick Smoke, which renders fine.

Here's the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38010

Tried both OpenCL and CPU rendering, Blender Internal as well as Cycles renderer. On Windows 7, i7 notebook with integrated amd graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to check Render in the outliner[image]